# Do we have Quick Watch in visual studio 2010 express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, express

I could not find Quick Watch in visual studio 2010 express. Do we only have the option for watch option and not quick watch in express editions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the **Quickwatch** feature is not available in Express editions of Visual Studio.

- It is a myth that it is only available from C++. Here is a screenshot from Visual Studio 2010 Professional, showing the QuickWatch in use for an ASP.NET C# project:

  [image]
- It is a myth that the key can be manually bound in Express editions. The command `Debug.QuickWatch`, while available in for-pay versions of Visual Studio:

  [image]

  is not available in Express editions (tested in 2008, 2010, 2012):

  [image]
- it is a myth that pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> will make the **QuickWatch** window appear in Express editions
- it is a myth that selecting

  2010 Express: Tools -> Import and Export settings -> Reset All settings
  2012 Express: Tools -> Settings -> Reset

  will restore the ability to have a QuickWatch in Express editions.

---

From MSDN: [How to: Use the QuickWatch Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> ```
> Visual Studio Edition  Visual Basic  C#   C++  J#
> =====================  ============  ===  ===  ===
> Express                No            No   No   No
> Standard               No            No   No   No
> Pro/Team               Yes           Yes  Yes  Yes
> ```
>
> Some users might, therefore, wonder why QuickWatch is useful. Why not simply add the variable or expression to the Watch window? Well, you could do that, but suppose you simply want to do a quick scratch calculation involving one or more variables? You don't want to clutter up the Watch window with such calculations. That's where QuickWatch comes in.
>
> Another nice feature of the QuickWatch dialog box is the fact that it's resizable. If you want to look at the members of a large object, it's often easier to expand and look at the tree QuickWatch than it is in the Watch, Locals, or Autos window.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio *Express* 2010 the QuickWatch dialog is available **only for C++**, any other language does **not support** that feature.

See this topic on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The Quick Watch feature should be available even in express SKUs of Visual Studio.  What's likely happening is the particular menu isn't visible by default for some reason in the current profile.  You can verify this is the case by doing the following while debugging

- View -> Other Windows -> Command Window
- Debug.QuickWatch theExpression

The `Debug.QuickWatch` command will directly invoke the quick watch feature.  It will act exactly as if you'd type `theExpression` into the quick watch window.

Comment: This is incorrect, at least for VS2013 Express. Not only that QuickWatch is not available in VS2013 Express, I don't even see Command Window in View > Other Windows.